# PrePersit current user

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

**[SETTINGS]**

- Symfony 3.4
- Logged user (FosUserBundle)
- `Projet` Entity (below)

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Entity/Projet.php**</kbd>

```
class Projet {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $titre;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation", type="datetime")
     */
    private $creation;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="modification", type="datetime")
     */
    private $modification;
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="projet")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updatedTimestamps() {
        $this->setModification(new \DateTime());
        if($this->getCreation() == null) {
            $this->setCreation(new \DateTime());
            $this->setSupprime(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**[PROBLEM]**

As is, I'm setting `creation` and `modification` on `PrePersit`/`PreUpdate`.
I would like to also set the id of the current logged user, how can I do it?

Comment: Where do you set anything? Couldn't you fetch the user entity at the same place and use that user's ID?

Comment: On a side note, considering the behaviour you set up with lifecycle events for `creation` and `modification` datetime fields, maybe you should consider using the [Timestampable doctrine extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) which handles this with a simple annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to have access to the `security.token_storage` service and call `$tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()` to retrieve the current user. Since it is not really recommended to inject a service into an entity, you should create an entity listener as described in [this section of the doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners).

Then, by declaring your entity listener as a service and adding the `security.token_storage` to its constructor arguments like this (in your `services.yml`):

```
listener.projet:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\ProjetListener
    arguments: [ "@security.token_storage" ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, lazy: true }
```

You would be able to access the currently logged in user inside your `prePersist` and `preUpdate` methods.

---

**Edit:** Here is how your listener should look like

<kbd>AppBundle/Listener/ProjetListener.php</kbd>

```
namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Projet;

class ProjetListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function prePersist(Projet $projet, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // Assigning the current user to the Projet instance being persisted
        $projet->setUser($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
        /* .. other actions of prePersist .. */
    }

    public function preUpdate(Projet $projet, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        /* .. actions of preUpdate .. */
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this how it should be? https://www.dropbox.com/s/fto9hp36srrw84q/projetListener.png?dl=0

Comment: @Preciel Not quite, you should expect `LifecycleEventArgs` not `PrePersist`. I added the skeleton of the listener you would need in my post.

Comment: Oh, I see.. was close... Can I also move the prePersist/preUpdate for the date in this listener?!

Comment: @Preciel yes, actually you should. For those fields, as pointed out in my other comment, you could consider using the [Timestampable doctrine extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do this in a subscriber, listening on prepersist and preupdate doctrine event.
You will be able to get the currentn user by injecting the security.token_storage service