# postPersist action - persist another entity

Tags: php, symfony, entitylisteners

**[EDITS]**

- Based on [goto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235811/goto) answer, I edited the `ProjectListener.php` file.

**[SETTINGS]**

- Symfony 3.4
- `Projet` entity
- Other child entities
- [Related to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522686/prepersit-current-user)

**[PROBLEM]**

Each time a `Projet` entity is persisted, it should be followed by some child entites.

I currently have a `ProjetListener` class which handle `prePersist()` and `preUpdate()` and `postPersist()` events.

<kbd>**AppBundle/Listener/ProjetListener.php**</kbd>

```
class ProjetListener {
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage) {
        $this->tokenStorage=$tokenStorage;
    }

    public function prePersist(Projet $projet, LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $projet->setUtilisateur($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser())
               ->setCreation(new \DateTime())
               ->setModification(new \DateTime())
               ->setSupprime(false);
    }

    public function preUpdate(Projet $projet, PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {
        $projet->setModification(new \DateTime());
    }

    public function postPersist(Projet $projet, LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $tremie=new Tremie();
        $tremie->setPosition(false)
               ->setForme(0)
               ->setTra(2000)
               ->setTr1(2000)
               ->setTr2(2000)
               ->setTre3(2000)
               ->setDecalTra(0)
               ->setDebordTr1(0)
               ->setDebordTr2(0)
               ->setReculMax(3500)
               ->setProjet($projet);
        $em=$args->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($tremie);
    }
}
```

As soon as my `Projet` entity is persisted, I would like to persist one `Tremie` entity, and set `Projet` as it's parent.
As it's now, the `postPersist()` event doesn't persist a `Tremie` entity.

Symfony successfully create a `Projet` entity, but doesn't create a `Tremie`entity afterward.
There is no error returned.

What should be added/edited to persist `Tremie` as soon as `Projet` was persisted, and set `Projet`as his parent?

Comment: IMHO you are using doctrine listeners in a wrong way. In a listener you haven't context to determine how to link entities, this job should be done by using form or a custom service.
You should use listeners for automatic actions, like sending mails for example. What is the `Tremie` entity for `Project` ?

Comment: @Mcsky it's one of it's component. A `Projet` entity is made from various parts, some are generated with the `Projet`, some other can be added later. As true, I don't really need the `TremieListener` in this case... Will edit my post.

Comment: Why have you got to create your Tremie entity inside the listener ? Do you absolutely have to run this block of code each time you'll save a `Project` ?

Comment: Yes, `perPersist()` is needed to get the current logged user. As I had `prePersist/preUpdate` as annotation for the dateTime, I moved them in the listener. And the `postUpdate()` will always occur as there is a need to have some other child entity in the `Projet`. Thoses child entity are defaults, and cannont be removed, just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the entity manager using

```
$entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
```

You could maybe do: (I never tried it)

```
public function prePersist(Projet $projet, LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $projet->setUtilisateur($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser())
           ->setCreation(new \DateTime())
           ->setModification(new \DateTime())
           ->setSupprime(false);

    $tremie->setPosition(false)
           ->setForme(0)
           ->setTra(2000)
           ->setTr1(2000)
           ->setTr2(2000)
           ->setTre3(2000)
           ->setDecalTra(0)
           ->setDebordTr1(0)
           ->setDebordTr2(0)
           ->setReculMax(3500)
           ->setProjet($project);
    $args->getEntityManager()->persist($tremie);
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer while taking in account some of your modifications. Still no tremie is persisted.